# How do I put an image in VisualStudio with C#?

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio

I really don't know how to put an image in my form.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: Did you try searching the internets for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE that helps you to create applications... You need to do your own research and then come back with any *clearly defined* problems you have in implementing that research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is WindowsForms that you are using, you can use the PictureBox control.

Comment: PictureBox only provides a container for an image, but then this assumes that the user is using winforms, and wants to show an image in a container (i.e not as background or others). This should be a comment.

Comment: Well, the user did say "I really don't know how to put an image in my form"... see - form... that is why I assumed it was windows forms. And it seems like my assumption was correct since my answer got accepted :)